# Is it generally bad practice to have many "initWith" parameters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Say for instance I have an implementation of a UIView. The UIView contains a two labels, an image and a frame.

My "init" method ends up looking like:

```
- (id)initWithFrameAndLabelArrayAndImage:(CGRect)frame:(NSArray *)labelArray:(UIImage *)image;
```

Is that considered bad practice? Is it better to have a simple "initWithFrame" method and have the other label and picture as @properties?

Comment: What did you end up concluding?

Answer (score 7):

It's fine.  Apple does it frequently.  For example, look at NSString:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html

```
– initWithBytes:length:encoding:
– initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:
– initWithCharacters:length:
– initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:
– initWithString:
– initWithCString:encoding:
– initWithUTF8String:
– initWithFormat:
– initWithFormat:arguments:
– initWithFormat:locale:
– initWithFormat:locale:arguments:
– initWithData:encoding:
```

But, following those patterns, yours:

```
- (id)initWithFrameAndLabelArrayAndImage:(CGRect)frame:(NSArray *)labelArray:(UIImage*)image;
```

Should probably be:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame labels:(NSArray *)labelArray image:(UIImage *)image;
```

Now, having said that, I probably wouldn't pass an array of labels.  I would pass the data and have the custom view take that data and create/layout the subviews.  You're sort of exposing the internal views that compose your custom view in the public methods and you may want to change how you render and compose them in the future.

Another approach would be to use delegates to render the labels the labels would be rendered by calling the delegate for the data it needs - similar to a table view.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 5):

Although having multiple paramaters is fine, you really shouldn't have any parameters that are unnamed.  In your case, to call your method it would look like this:

```
[[* alloc] initWithFrameAndLabelArrayAndImage:frame :array :image];
```

This is generally bad practice.  I would rearrange your custom initializer to be more along the following lines:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame labelArray:(NSArray *)labelArray image:(UIImage *)image;
```

or even

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andLabels:(NSArray *)labels andImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically a matter of preference, but I personally like to create "convenience methods" whenever I find my parameter list running amok (ie, shorter-named messages that call the longer ones using default values). For instance...

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame {
 [self initWithFrame:frame andLabel:@"Default text"];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andLabel: (NSString *) str {
...
}
...
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andLabel: (NSString *) str ... andMothersMaidenName:(id) etc { ... }
```

I do question why you would use "initWithFrameAndLabelArrayAndImage:" as your first parameter, though, rather than just `initWithFrame: andLabel: andArray: andImage:.` Adding all the parameters to the first parameter name (and then repeating them in the subsequent ones) just seems redundant to me.